# Make awk interpret one line at a time from variable

Tags: bash, shell, awk, echo

I'm a completely new to shell scripting and bash. My question is how do I get awk to interpret a variable which contains linebreaks the same way as awk interpret the data from stdin?

Example:

```
fileData=`cat /path/to/file`
echo $fileData | awk '{print $1}'
```

The code above results in the following error message: `awk: program limit exceeded: maximum number of fields size=32767` which obviously means that awk interprets all the lines in `$fileData` at the same time and not one line at a time.

How to make awk interpret one line at a time from a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly, I suspect that your issue is less todo with `awk`, and more to do with shell white-space splitting.  Your problem is that the shell has taken the new-lines inside `$fileData` as white-space field seperators.  To prevent that:

```
echo "$fileData" | awk '{print $1}'
```

You can also access environment variables (`export fileData`) directly from `awk` using the associative array `environ`, for example `environ["fileData"]`, however it is probably a bad strategy to store an entire file contents in a variable because of the risk of busting memory.

By the way, I hope that your code is just a simple example,

```
awk '{print $1}' /path/to/file
```

is much preferred.  As is:

```
fileData=$(cat /path/to/file)
```

over using backticks (although `cat` is rarely necessary).

Comment: So just some quotes that needed to be added, THANK YOU! And yes, my example code was just a silly example to illustrate the issue! What is the difference between using backticks and `$(...)`?

Comment: In bash at least, `$( < /path/to/file)` is equivalent and more efficient, since `bash` reads the file directly, rather than spawning a process to run `cat`.

Comment: @Bazze: the difference between backticks and `$(...)` is readability, functionally they are the same.